# Install Tensorflow to Existing Anaconda Environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Due to some write permission on my new computer, I can only install to the base(root) environment. How can I add tensorflow to the root environment? Everything I have seen for install has been to create a new environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
conda activate base
conda install -c anaconda pip
pip install tensorflow
```

After that, you can clone from base to create new environments.

Comment: Is there any reason not to do this? Why create a separate environment?

Comment: Well, environments primarily exist to isolate projects. Every project has its own set of dependencies. Thus, you can ship your project to any platform just by listing all packages installed in your development environment. If you don't do that, you might have to deal with dependencies manually. The idea to have a separate environment with the specific package is a nice idea: it (the environment) can be used as a bootstrapper for other projects.

Comment: Isn't the base environment copied over anyway when a new environment is created? Also, why does Anaconda put `scikit-learn` in the base environment (how is it different from TF)?

Comment: A late reply: Yes, new environments are automatically cloned from base. Anacaonda is intended to be a manager for datascience projects, that is why it has many tools already embedded in it (like numpy, scikit-learn, pandas etc.). You can install miniconda that is a smaller version of anaconda (a.k.a does not have those libs in it.)